# Angular 4 reload route based on path parameter change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have looked at several examples but I can't seem to get the subscribe function for the params observable to work. I am able to get router.events to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ProjectService } from '../../services/project.service';
import { Project } from "../../domain/project";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html'
})
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {

  projects: Project[] = [];


  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService,
              private route : ActivatedRoute,
              private router : Router) {

    this.projectService.getProjects();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.projectService.projectsChange.subscribe(result => {
      this.projects = result;
    });

    this.projectService.projectChange.subscribe(result => {
      this.projectService.getProjects();
    });

    // This only works the first time the component is routed to
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      console.log("did this work at all?");
      this.projectService.getProject(params['id']);
    });

    // This works when the param changes in the router
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(this.router.url);
      let url = this.router.url;
      let id = url.substring(url.length - 2, url.length);
      this.projectService.getProject(Number(id));
    });

  }
}
```

This is the route (child)

```
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'projects/:id', component: ProjectComponent }
    ]
  }
```

This is how the links are setup within the template

```
[routerLink]="['/projects/', project.id]"
```

Comment: Do you get an errors with this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe?

Comment: no errors, just NavigationStart, RoutesRecognized and NavigationEnd with the correct url.

Comment: hmm, can you post some more of your component.ts code? (constructor, activatedRoute import, etc) Are you subscribing in your constructor or an ngOnInit lifecycle hook?

Comment: please see edit

Comment: Is NavBarComponent loaded into the parent compnent DashboardComponent or into each child component (ProjectComponent)?

Comment: its loaded once into the parent component "Dashboard"

Comment: ah ok, I have a similar issue in my current project. Since your NavDashboard component exists in the parent router outlet you need to subscribe to params in the child router outlet (since you are looking for param changes in the child outlet) Try this.activatedRoute.firstChild.params.subscribe()

Comment: I couldn't get firstChild or children to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151897/discussion-between-llai-and-grimlek).

Answer (score 2):

Thnx to LLai within discussion, the issue was boiled down to the fact that I was trying to use the code below from within the wrong component.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
  console.log("did this work at all?");
  this.projectService.getProject(params['id']);
});
```

Comment: Newer versions of the Angular router suggest accessing router params via `paramMap` rather than `params`. [Docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar use case and the following code works for me:

```
export class ProductDetailComponent {

  productID: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe(
        params => this.productID = params.get('id'));
  }
}
```

In the parent component I have a list of products and pass the selected product ID as follows:

```
  constructor(private _router: Router){}

  onSelect(prod: Product): void {
    this.selectedProduct = prod;
    this._router.navigate(["/productDetail", prod.id]);
  }
```

I don't use routerLink, but this should make no difference.